# Form drop down(spinner) & trying to change the value to the selected items value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, android-spinner

I am using a form spinner(essentially a form drop down in android terms.)
I want to be able to change the value to the selected spinner item instead of what it does now which is nothing.

How can I make it so that it does change value when selected?

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benlevygraphics/UPCUH/) with a working spinner but its not changing values on select yet

Here is the html code that makes the spinner:

```
<div class="form-spinner">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="toggle-spinner">Set Repetition</a>
            <ul class="spinner">
                <li class="spinner-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Once</a></li>
                <li class="spinner-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Daily</a></li>
                <li class="spinner-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Weekly</a></li>
                <li class="spinner-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Monthly</a></li>
                <li class="spinner-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Custom</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @I want to be able to change the value to the selected spinner item instead of what is does now which is nothing

Comment: Yeah I suspected you wanted that :) but what is the question?

Comment: Where are you stuck in specific? Stack overflow is not a code generation tool.

Comment: making the spinner change to the selected items value when selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to update the text on click

```
$('.spinner-item').click(function (item){
    $('.toggle-spinner').text( $(this).text());
});
```